# How to intercept and suppress email?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, email

How can I listen for incoming email and, if it matches a particular profile (based on subject, for instance), intercept it so that it can be processed without displaying it to the user?

Comment: Where would you expect this "interceptor" to run? The mail client? Server?

Comment: The recipient app will intercept it. My complementary apps are 1) A "Metro" app, running on a tablet, and 2) A WP8 app. They will both send and receive email to each other, but handle them "invisibly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest looking for Layered Service Provider. Not .net (low low WinAPI) but seems to work for this case perfectly.